# How to validate a string posted is utf-8 and not html?

Tags: php, validation

Need to validate whether the submitted string is under UTF-8 and not html

How to do this in php?

i tried

```
mb_check_encoding($string, 'UTF-8');

mb_check_encoding($string, 'html');
```

Any other easy way?

Comment: `html` is not an encoding.

Comment: how to validate could you please share..

Comment: In simplest sense - encoding is rule(s) -  How international characters are encoded into bytes. So html document has encoding too

Comment: The question is what do you want to achive as result?

Answer (score 0):

So far simplest way to check if string is compatible with UTF-8 is to execute regex match on string in Unicode mode:

```
$string = hex2bin('ffee0014aa'); // bad UTF8 mockup
preg_match('//u', $string);
echo preg_last_error()==PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR ? 'BAD_UTF8' : 'GOOD_UTF8';
```

Outputs:

> BAD_UTF8